# Inserindo Script em código Android para busca em SearchView

Tags: javascript, java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Android que trabalha com a API do Google Maps, e nele tenho uma searchView que precisa fazer a busca do local digitado e exibir no mapa. Porém eu não sei como se insere um script (dei uma pesquisada e em sua maioria os códigos que conseguem fazer tal busca, o fazem com código em JavaScript). 
Segue meu código:

XML da tela do mapa:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.vitor.agrvaimaps.ActPrincipal"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_act_principal">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="382dp"
        android:layout_height="510dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

    </FrameLayout>

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:queryHint="Pesquise um Local"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

O Codigo da Activity:

```
  public class ProviderV2 extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = "ProviderV2";

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker marker;
    private SearchView busca;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getMapAsync(this);


    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //Ativa GPS
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 100, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {



        try {

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


            mMap = googleMap;

            mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);

            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);



        }catch (SecurityException ex){
            Log.e(TAG,"Erro", ex);
        }




        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                if(marker != null){
                    marker.remove();
                }

                customAddMarker( new LatLng(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude), "Novo Local", "Clique aqui para adicionar aos favoritos!");

            }
        });

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) { // MARKER CLICK LISTENER

                return false;
            }
        });

        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                //Marcador

            }
        }); // CLICAR NO DROPMENU DO MARKER




    }

    public void setOnSearchClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){ //METODO QUE ATIVA O LISTENER DO BOTAO DE PESQUISA

    //Aqui é onde preciso inserir o script para busca do local

    }


@Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
       Toast.makeText( getContext(),"Coordenadas: " + latLng.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Não funcional
    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Você se moveu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        Toast.makeText( getContext(),"Status Alterado. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText( getContext(),"Provider Habilitado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText( getContext(),"Provider Desabilitado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    public void customAddMarker(LatLng latLng, String title, String snippet){
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
        options.position(latLng).title(title).snippet(snippet).draggable(true);

        marker = mMap.addMarker(options);
    }


}
```